# What is the end of line character that stops reading data into an array from the keyboard?

Tags: arrays, perl

When I want to read the data from the keyboard in Perl I use the code below, but it keeps on waiting for data.

What character will inform the program that the user has completed their input?

#### program

```
@array = <STDIN>;
$Size = @array;

for ( $i = 0; $i < $size; $i++ ) {
   print "$i"."$array[$i]";
}
```

**Note:** Sometimes when I use Ctrl-Z it shows the correct result, but this is not working all the time. I am using the Eclipse IDE with Perl plugin.

Comment: You also have a typo in your program. $Size and $size refer to different variables. It is also recommended to add 'use strict;' and 'use warnings;' at the top of your program to warn you when possible errors like this happen.

Comment: Note that `for ( $i = 0; $i < $size; $i++ ) { ... }` is generally written `for my $i ( 0 .. $#array) { ... }`

Answer (score 5):

[`perldoc -f readline`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/readline.html) says that in list context, `readline` (which is the `<>` operator you are using) reads until the end-of-file is reached and returns a list of lines.

Are you running your program using a shell like bash? If that's the case then the end-of-file character is Ctrl-D (hold <kbd>CTRL</kbd> and press <kbd>D</kbd>).

Comment: As i specified as a note in my question i am using the eclipse ide with perl plugin. and cctrl+z is working some times and it is not some times.

Comment: I'm not sure about Eclipse but it should be running your program in a shell. Are you running Eclipse in Linux or Mac or Windows PC?

Answer (score 2):

In every shell, `EOF` has to be the first character in response to a `readline`. So, the user would have to type <kbd>CTRL-Z</kbd> (DOS/Windows shells) or <kbd>CTRL-D</kbd> (*nixy shells) as the first character in a line to terminate input.

This is because you are using a slurpy method of reading from standard input by doing `@array = <STDIN>`. That means your program will try to read lines from standard input until input is exhausted. Your program depends on the shell/terminal to determine when the input is exhausted (I am ignoring file redirection).

```
$ ./myprog
some input⏎
some more input⏎
CTRL-D
```

would work. On the other hand,

```
$ ./myprog
some input⏎
some more inputCTRL-D
```

would not. In this case, pressing <kbd>CTRL-D</kbd> twice may be sufficient to terminate input. However, in DOS/Windows shells, pressing <kbd>CTRL-Z</kbd> multiple times is not going to have that effect.

If you switch to reading from `<STDIN>` line by line, your program can do things in response to each line entered instead of having to wait for all the lines to be read. E.g.:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my @input;

while (my $line = <STDIN>) {
    last if $line !~ /\S/; # stop reading if input is all whitespace
    push @input, $line;
}

for my $line ( @input ) {
    print $line;
}
```